# how can I stop someone from watching my internet history?

Tags: network, privacy, anonymity, internet

I use someone's wifi network. Is there anyway to stop him by getting my browsing information or can I somehow hide my browsing history from him?

Answer (score 1):

Use a VPN to a trusted endpoint, or at least visit only sites over HTTPS.  (There he'll still be able to know which servers you connect to, but not which pages you request.)  You could also consider using something TOR to tunnel all your traffic (as it also encrypts all traffic).

Comment: How can I use TOR to encrypt my network traffic??

Comment: Will you please tell me more in detail?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an answer to your question, just a suggestion to calm your nerves.

If its a normal router configuration then none of your traffic will ever reach his other devices. If the router goes through a software proxy/reverse proxy (the router isn't plugged directly into the modem) then they could potentially look at your traffic.

Odds are its a normal router configuration and you have nothing to worry about. There aren't a whole lot of people with the technical know-how to snoop on you, odds are you neighbor isn't one of them.

Comment: How can I install SSL PROXY in my system in addition to solve this problem?

Comment: The person doesn't live in my country.  He just settled up wi-fi and went away. Still he can access to my browsing history??